# Git like pagers and editor handling in C

Tags: c

I am working on a C project where I want to use external CLI programs such as `less` as a pager and `nano` or `vi` as an editor to submit multi-line messages. The idea came to me from Git. Like when we use say `git commit` without `-m` an editer is executed to enable multi-line commit messages. And with `git log` a pager like `less` is executed to enable content navigation.

The idea is to reproduce the same behavior. Except for the pager where there is some more subtleties to it. The content I am willing to display is retrieved from a remote server and must be retrieved part by part like a infinite scroll. Which means I need to somehow know when the pager has consumed all the content given to it, retrieve more content and append it to what has already been displayed.

So what I am looking for is:

- Some suggestions and advice on the methods with which I can implement
  these functionalities.
- Standard tools or libraries that can be helpful on this context (such
  as gnulib modules).
- Subtleties I must be paying attention to when working on it in order to
  build a robust program.

I understand that this is not a precise question, and I am expecting it to result on a long discussion.

Comment: Generally you do this by setting/reading the PAGER, EDITOR and VISUAL environment variables. Most tools will honor these. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Environment_Variables As for the "part by part" bit, that's unnecessary because IO buffering will take care of that for you. Just keep printing to the pager and the buffers will handle it. Also, SO is not for discussions. Maybe try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Schwern The remote server I was talking about is a web API, ie. When requesting data from it I have to specify offset and limit, otherwise the server will retrieve the whole database table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `popen` the pager and write to the FILE that popen gives you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int produce(FILE *f){
    for(int i=0; i<1000000;i++){
        if(0>fprintf(f,"printing line %d\n", i))
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
   FILE *out;
   if(0==(out = popen("$PAGER", "w"))){
       perror("popen"); 
       return 1;
   }
   return -produce(out);

}
```

The behavior you want is naturally part of pipe-based IPC.
Your equivalent of my produce function should simply try to fetch the content from the server chunk by chunk and write it to the file (pipe) chunk by chunk until all is fetched and written.

Pagers do not consume all their input at once and because of this, the thread/process in which the produce function resides will be blocked when it fills up the pipe buffer and only resumed when the pager (the process/thread at the read end of the pipe) empties the pipe buffer by reading more text from its stdin.

Pipe buffers are usually around 8KiB by default which means that unless you reset the pipe buffer with fcntl to a different size (which might be desirable in your situation), your producer will be allowed to fetch and write something over 8KiB before it gets blocked (it will get unblocked (=> allowed to continue fetching) once the user has scrolled down past the 8KiB and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Open a pipe to the pager and use `select` to determine when it's ready to read more.

Here's an example. I'm going to do this in Perl because I don't know how to pipe to a pager in C. The basic interface is the same. This will print a large list of numbers, but only when the pager is ready for more.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use IO::Select;
use IO::Handle;
use Carp;
use v5.10;

# Open a filehandle to the pager or if there's no pager to STDOUT.
sub open_pager {
    my $pager = $ENV{PAGER};
    return \*STDOUT if !$pager;

    open my $fh, "|-", $pager;
    $fh->autoflush();
    return $fh;
}

# Watch the pager filehandle.
my $select = IO::Select->new;
$select->add(open_pager());

# Wait until the pager is ready to read.
# (Note: it always returns a list of ready filehandles)
my $num = 0;
while( my @fhs = $select->can_write) {
    # Write to the pager and also to STDOUT so we can see
    # when the writing is happening.
    for my $fh (@fhs) {
        say $fh $num;
        say STDERR "Sending $num";
    }
    $num++;
}
```

Note that this is inexact. On my machine initially it will send a large block up to 3712 to fill up the pager's read buffer. Afterwards the pager will be ready to read more well ahead of what it's displaying.

It's enough to prevent you from wasting a bunch of bandwidth, and will give you better granularity than relying on blocking on a filled output buffer.